# How can I connect redis running on my machine from my app running in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, redis, pm2

My nodejs app is running in a docker container. And I'm using bull queue for the background services which uses redis.

I have redis installed on my machine and when I try to run the queue in pm2 I'm unable to connect to redis
Here's the config for redis in my app

```
"redis" : {
    "host": "192.168.1.98",
    "port": "6379"
  }
```

Here's the error

```
0|stockProcessor  | WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
0|stockProcessor  | WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
0|stockProcessor  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
0|stockProcessor  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14) {
0|stockProcessor  |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|stockProcessor  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|stockProcessor  |   syscall: 'connect',
0|stockProcessor  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
0|stockProcessor  |   port: 6379
0|stockProcessor  | }
0|stockProcessor  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
0|stockProcessor  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14) {
0|stockProcessor  |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|stockProcessor  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|stockProcessor  |   syscall: 'connect',
0|stockProcessor  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
0|stockProcessor  |   port: 6379
0|stockProcessor  | }
```

Config injection

```
const Queue = require("bull");
const configR = require("config");

const redisConfig = configR.get("redis");

const constants = require("../constants");

const config = {
  settings: {
    stalledInterval: 5000,
    maxStalledCount: 9999,
    lockDuration: 60000,
    lockRenewTime: 30000
  }
};

const stockQueue = new Queue("stockQueue", redisConfig, config);
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a configuration error because the above shows that your app is attempting to connect to your loop back interface and not the LAN address you posted above. Please share the code where you inject the desired configuration.

Comment: above host and port is configured in my config file

When i log the redisConfig variable I get the correct IP and port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/HEAD/REFERENCE.md#queue) it looks like the second parameter in the `constructor` should be a string instead of an object. It looks like you could add your redis config option to the `config` object to connect to it, or build a string from your redis config object.

P.S. I've not used bull before, so it might be that the documentation is incorrect here and your way of passing properties is allowed

Comment: Thanks you Bas for pointing this out. It works now.